# Python graphics setText overwrites original text

Tags: python

I'm using graphics.py to get operator selections in a window.
When a button has been selected, I want to change some text to the next instruction. The result of the code below is that the new text is added to the window instead of replacing the original.
The rest of the code in this sample works fine.

```
def which_channel():
Word5=Text(Point(56,70),"Click the channel to use")
Word5.draw(win)
p=win.checkMouse()                          # Check for mouse click
if p==None:
    channel=3                               # if none, loop
else:
    if 55<p.getY()<65:                      # if pressed, see if it's in one of the buttons
        if 48<p.getX()<56:
            channel=0                       # set the channel
            Ch1.setFill("red")              # and mark the selected button
        elif 58<p.getX()<66:
            channel=1
            Ch2.setFill("red")

if channel!=3:                              # if a valid channel selected, change the text !!!!!!!
    Word5.setText("Channel selected")
return channel
```

I have 2 rectangles to act as buttons, user has to click one or other to select a valid channel, 0 or 1.
At the bottom of the snippet, if a valid channel has been selected (0 or 1) I want to alter the text to say so.
I simply get "Channel selected" superimposed on "Click the channel to use".
If I change the code to change the text colour, again I get both colours superimposed.
I've tried undraw and that doesn't work either, so I'm missing something.
Ideas about what's going wrong please.

Comment: I believe one problem is that you are recreating the Text every time you call this function. Create it beforehand and only change the text in the function.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks. Obvious now.

Comment: However this leaves me wondering why it didn't complain that I'd already created Word5 or told me that it was already drawn, as it would if I repeated the Word5.draw(win) command

Comment: Python never complains if reuse a name.

Answer (score 0):

You continuously replace the previous file. Change the text in the function, but don't recreate the file on each call.